# Intuition for hypergeometric variance?

Tags: distributions, variance, intuition, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm trying to learn the major facts about a bunch of probability distributions, hypergeometric included. I can use the commonalities between it and a binomial to my advantage for thinking through some of the formulas; for example, the mean is basically exactly the same. But the variance has me a little bit more stumped. For reference, the variance of a hypergeometric can be written as

$n(\frac{r}{N})(1-\frac{r}{N})(\frac{N-n}{N-1})$

where $N$ is the number of events in the universe, $n$ is the number of trials, and $r$ is the number of possible successes.

Most of those terms are pretty straightforward to me. Again, comparing to a binomial, $n(\frac{r}{N})(1-\frac{r}{N})$ is basically $npq$. And even in that last term, the numerator has a pretty straightforward intuition: the closer the number of trials is to the possible number of trials, the lower the variance will be, down even to zero; in the classic example of drawing colored marbles from a jar, if you draw every single marble then of course you will have no variance.

But it's the denominator that I'm not so sure about. Now, I understand that the variance can be derived from the moment generating function and so on, but I'm trying to gain the intuition. And I can understand that one effect the denominator has is that the more marbles there are in the jar, the higher the variance will be. Although I'm struggling to understand (intuitively) *why* that would necessarily be the case.

So, in the end, there's two facts about the variance of a hypergeometric that I'm struggling to gain the intuition for: 1) the inverse relationship between variance and $N$ (although that would be the case even without the last term) and 2) what work the $N-1$ is doing. So even though the title refers to the variance of the hypergeometric in general, in particular I'm focused on the **denominator** of the **last term** of the variance.

Comment: In a sense when $n=1$  the $N-1$ in the denominator balances the $N-n$ in the numerator as you want then want the variance of a single sample to equal the Bernouilli variance of $p(1-p)$. Similarly when $n=N-1$ the $N-1$ in the denominator  balances the $n$ in the numerator as you want the all-but-one variance  to equal the Bernouilli variance  of the one not selected.  So at each end $\frac{n(N-n)}{N-1}$ is intuitively right.   The intuition is harder when $n$ is some intermediate value, and that is when you resort to analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Originally a comment:*

In a sense when $n=1$ the $N−1$ in the denominator balances the $N−n$ in the numerator as you want then want the variance of a single sample to equal the Bernoulli variance of $p(1−p)$.

Similarly when $n=N−1$, the $N−1$ in the denominator balances the $n$ in the numerator as you want the all-but-one variance to equal the Bernoulli variance of the one not selected, given that they add up to a constant total.

So at each end $\frac{n(N−n)}{N−1}$ is intuitively right. The intuition is harder when $n$ is some intermediate value, and that is when you resort to analysis.